# Php artisan migrate creating only one table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I created three migrations with `php artisan make:migration` and after that I ran `php artisan migrate`. This command creating only one table in my database instead of 3.

Comment: try php artisan migrate:status and let me know the answer

Comment: if you want to create a migration that creates a table then you can use `php artisan make:migration --create=tablename` (of course you need to fill in the table structure)

Comment: after running the php artisan migrate:status  i got 2 columns
Ran? N,     and second one my table name

Comment: i created 3 migration with "php artisan make:migration create_table_name"

Comment: Not sure if you deleted tables directly, try php artisan migrate:refresh?

Comment: I tried with php artisan migrate:refresh and got "nothing to roll back"

Comment: I am using mac OS. Everything is working fine on windows but facing this issues on mac. Is there any restriction for mac?

Comment: Try running `php artisan migrate:refresh --verbose` to get a detailed breakdown. You may also wish to check our what has populated your `migrations` table in your database

Answer (score 0):

to make artisan migration create a new table your migration script must contains Schema::create not Schema::table. you can add this option to your command when generating the scripts --create=table_name

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('fonts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Comment: I am using Schema::create for all migrations. But it only creating one table.

Comment: please post all the migration scripts so that we can debug it

Answer (score 0):

`artisan migrate` does not open migrations that have previously run and are in the migrations table. Ergo if you have modified databases in your migration and deleted the table manually it will not recreate the table.

You would have to check the migrations table to check what migrations have run, and if the migrations you have run are in a row, delete that row manually. To future proof this, you would need to run migrate:rollback, provided the migration has a delete table in the `down` function.

Comment: i created new database and then i run php artisan migrate. It creates two tables in my database one is migration and other is users table but in my migration folder there are 3 tables. I should create 3 tables not one.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is go to the AppServiceProvider.php file and inside the boot method set a default string length:

[SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFK58.png)

Add these two:

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#creating-indexes